# Is there a problem with concrete patio that's next to the house and poured above the house's foundation?

Tags: concrete, patio

We're currently installing a patio. The contractor has laid it out in a way where the patio will be against siding, and will be above the foundation.  You can see on the picture below the dirt base for the patio, and how close it is to an electrical box, a water tap, and the red line / plain pencil line against the siding.  I'm not in love with this -- but is it just me?  Is this generally accepted concrete practice?  Thank you for any input!

[image: Patio Base on Siding]

Comment: Is that red line what the top of the patio's supposed to be aligned with? If so, I see a problem brewing....

Answer (score 4):

That's a hack job and will cause you problems down the line with rotting siding, evidently a hose bibb so close to the surface you won't be able to get a hose attached, and an illegal because you can't open it partially embedded junction box, for a start.

Comment: Yeah, big time, Ecnerwal. The patio should slop away from the house  and certainly not contact the siding at all. But even now, from your pics you have an issue:  Dirt in direct contact with siding. In my area we are required to keep dirt at least 6" below the siding.   So you already have a problem now.   Not sure of the layout of your house/land, but it would seem you have some excavating to do.

Comment: Yeah, I have 18 inches (stucco over foam over concrete foundation wall) before I start with wood, and I would not go much less than that.

Comment: Thank you all for the input I appreciate it!